# Catch App Terminate from LaunchDeamon

Tags: cocoa

I've got a Cocoa foundation tool that I run as a LaunchDeamon. When the app is terminated by the system, either by a reboot or shutdown (or even launchctl unload), is there a way I can capture this event so that I can perform some finalizing functions?

Answer (score 3):

All the cases you're discussing send `SIGTERM` to the process. You want to add a signal handler for that. See the man pages for [signal](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/signal.3.html) and [sigaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sigaction.2.html). Read the warnings carefully. Only certain functions are legal to call during a signal handler (and in principle you should never allocate heap memory). Generally it's best to just use the handler to set a flag that tells your main thread to terminate.

You may also want to look at [PreLoginAgents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PreLoginAgents/Listings/PreLoginAgentCocoa_main_m.html) for an example of how to handle `SIGTERM` using the run loop, if you're using a run loop.

See [Terminating Processes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Lifecycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW3-BAJJBJEG) in the Daemons and Services Programming Guide for full details on what signals will be sent to your process.

Comment: I have a server that needs to know when the client machine is turning off. Would sending an http json request be more than what can happen during a signal trap?

Comment: Yes. You should schedule for this to happen on the main loop. Basically, you should catch the SIGTERM and set something internally that says "I should quit now" and return. Then your main program should note the "I should quit now," and you should do whatever you need to do (like talk to the server), then exit. Trying to do all of that in the middle of a signal handler is dangerous and could hang the program (even spiking one of the cores to 100% utilization if you get very unlucky).

Comment: Thanks Rob - I've modified my code to include a `signal(SIGTERM, sigCatch)`. It gets called if I do sudo launchctl unload, but it doesn't get called when a system reboot takes place.

Comment: See the link I added above for all the ways that hooks available. Normal reboots, however, should send SIGTERM. Make sure you're not calling `enableSuddenTermination`, but this is a fairly new technology that you probably aren't using by accident (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I have not intentionally enabled suddenTermination. Still no luck with receiving a SIGTERM during reboot though.

Comment: Click the apple logo then reboot or shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

All `NSObject` subclasses call a method before dying: [`- finalize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/finalize). There is also `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` for dealing with crashes.

Comment: Since I'm using a foundation tool, my main class is not an NSObject

Comment: In any case, there is no promise that `finalize` will be called, particularly in response to an uncaught SIGTERM, or in a non-GC environment.